# e.target is body on click when context menu is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I have this event:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
   var $target = $(e.target);
   if ($target.is('.element')) {
      console.log('element');
   }
});
```

And I have this issue:

When I right click to show context menu and then click on `.element` (when context menu is visible) the `e.target` is `body` not `.element` in Chrome.

How can I detect if I click on `.element`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolve the issue by adding this code:

```
function inside(element, x, y) {
    var offset = element.offset();
    var width = element.outerWidth();
    var height = element.outerHeight();
    return (x > offset.left && y > offset.top &&
            x < (offset.left + width) && y < (offset.top + height));
}

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
   e = e.originalEvent;
   var inside_elements = $('.element').get().filter(function(element) {
       return inside(element, e.pageX, e.pageY);
   });
   if (inside_elements.length) {
      console.log('element');
   }
});
```

**EDIT**: and found another solution using this:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
   e = e.originalEvent;
   var node = document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY);
   var $target = $(node);
   if ($target.is('.element')) {
      console.log('element');
   }
});
```

**EDIT2** weird enough this don't happen when I've try to recreate the issue in codepen, maybe it's something with focus/blur of textarea on click.